# xCode 4.6 Object alloc and init

Tags: nsobject, xcode4.6

I'm new to xCode. I'm using xCode 4.6 and I don't understand how xcode instantiates objects fully.
I thought that if you declare the object as a property in the .h file it automatically alloc and init it. the only way I could get my code to work is to do the alloc and init on the property file. I included my sample code below, but can anyone tell me if this is the right way to do this?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int age;

@end

#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

@end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Person.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Person *person;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDisplay;
- (IBAction)btnChangeLabel:(id)sender;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _person = [[Person alloc]init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnChangeLabel:(id)sender {

    [_person setName:@"Rich"];
    [_person setAge:50];
    _lblDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is %d years old.",_person.name,_person.age];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the right thing, except in your btnChangeLabel method, refer to your properties via:

```
self.person.name = @"Rich";
self.person.age = 50;
_lblDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is %d years old.",self.person.name,self.person.age];
```

The only time you want to use the underlying variables "_person" is when you need to allocate the space for them.  The rest of the time, you'll use their accessors (getters and setters; which is what the "`self.person.name =`" thing is doing). This way the compiler will know to do ARC-style releases and retains automagically.